# Scalar UDF does not return expected value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm working in SSMS 2012.  I have the following scalar UDF:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[test] (@input nvarchar)
RETURNS nvarchar
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @output nvarchar
    SET @output = CASE
        WHEN @input IS NULL THEN 'failure'
        WHEN @input = '' THEN 'failure'
        ELSE 'success'
    END
    RETURN @output
END
```

I have to grant permissions on it.  So, I enter:

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON [dbo].[test] TO Public
```

I am calling this UDF in the WHERE clause of the following query:

```
SELECT
Col1
FROM some_table
WHERE
[dbo].[test](Col2) = 'failure'
```

In some_table, I know that Col2 has records that are NULL.  So, these records should have returned, since the output from the UDF should be 'failure'.  However, the query doesn't return any records.  Where am I going wrong?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length) - you should **always** provide a length for any `varchar` variables and parameters that you use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an issue with your deceleration.

Change

```
RETURNS varchar
```

to

```
RETURNS varchar(50)
```

your function is returning 'f' or 's'